# I want my view controllers to have the same combination of custom UIViews which communicate with each other

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview

I want my several view controllers to have a player in the bottom. This player consists of 2 views: the player and a button which toggles it (can be hidden or expanded).

[image: Expanded version]

[image: Hidden]

Now I use the code below in each view controller to add this player.

```
@IBOutlet weak var broadcastView: BroadcastView!
@IBOutlet weak var broadcastViewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var avatarImageView: UIImageView!

@IBAction func toggleBroadcastMode(_ sender: ToggleBroadcastButton) {
    if sender.isExpanded {
        broadcastViewBottomConstraint.hideBroadcastView()
    } else {
        broadcastViewBottomConstraint.expandBroadcastView()
    }
    animateBroadcastToggle()

    sender.toggle()
    broadcastView.toggleBroadcastView()
}
```

Is there a way not to duplicate the code over and over? Maybe I can create parent VC or View to do it? If so, then how?

Comment: You can use `containerview`.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed explanation 'cause I never used it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would subclass a UINavigationController and have it in there, that way you can navigate through the flow while the player stays looking good at the bottom, if you need a VC to interact with it then you can

```
if let nav = navigationController as? MyPlayerNavController {
    nav.PlayThis()
}
```

you can have it change size and everything from there and you wont lose it during transitions and stuff like the music app when playing music.

Answer (score 0):

Add it as a subview of the keyWindow. That way it will always stay in all the viewControllers.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    var overlayViewFrame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    overlayViewFrame.origin.y = overlayViewFrame.height - 200
    overlayViewFrame.size.height = 200
    let overlayView = UIView(frame:overlayViewFrame)
    overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(overlayView)
}
```

This code is a sample generic code. If you want certain VCs to not show this, keep this overlay view in a singleton, and hide in appropriate VCs.

Output screenshots:
[image]
[image]